# IModelBinderProvider webapi equivalent

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding

What would be equivalent of IModelBinderProvider in WEBAPI?
I have read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/05/11/webapi-parameter-binding-under-the-hood.aspx) by still not understand how to replace default binding or insert its own binding rules.

**EDIT:** Current 'classic' MVC model binder provider (implements IModelBinderProvider).

```
public IModelBinder GetBinder(Type modelType)
        {
            Type binderType;

            lock (_syncLock)
            {
                // Check to see if a type was already bound.
                if (_binders.ContainsKey(modelType))
                    binderType = _binders[modelType];
                else
                {
                    // Check the assembly and look for a <name>ModelBinder
                    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                    Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();

                    // Convention over configuration
                    binderType = types.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == modelType.Name + "ModelBinder");

                    if (binderType != null)
                        _binders[modelType] = binderType;
                }
            }

            if (binderType == null)
                return null;

            var binder = (IModelBinder) DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(binderType);
            return binder;
        }
```

So you can see I am trying to use dependency resolver for binder selection.

Also in configuration I replaced default binder with

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(ObjectFactory.Container));
```

At the end if I send parameter (as form or querystring) in example "LocationID" and I have webapi action like this

```
public HttpResponseMessage MyAction(MyCls obj) {
   // do something
}

public class MyCls{
    public string LocationID {get;set;}
}
```

I need MyCls to be bound and LocationID to get value of provided "LocationID" param.

Comment: web API, in practice, has clear separation between whether the parameter comes from the body or not. What is it that you want to modify with a custom parameter binding?

Comment: I will modify question with copy of code currently used for default parameter binding in classic MVC.